# How to save a wav file on the server in PHP if it has been sent using XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, php, post, recorder.js

I am using the following snippet to send a wav file as a blob to the server which is written in PHP:

```
function upload(blob) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/upload.php', true);
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        var result = e.target.result;
    };

    xhr.send(blob);
}
```

I am confused as to how I should handle the POST data on the server.

Comment: Are you just looking for how to parse POST data in php? if so, try http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [php://input](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input):

```
$fp = fopen("php://input", "r");
$wav_file = stream_get_contents($fp);
```

Note that I'm assuming `blob` in your example is an actual [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), or [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer), or [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File), and not just a bunch of text whose UTF8 interpretation is also a valid WAVE file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" id="uploadfile" name="uploadfile" />
<input type="button" value="upload" onclick="upload()" />



<script>
   var client = new XMLHttpRequest();

   function upload() 
   {
      var file = document.getElementById("uploadfile");

      /* Create a FormData instance */
      var formData = new FormData();
      /* Add the file */ 
      formData.append("upload", file.files[0]);

      client.open("post", "/upload", true);
      client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
      client.send(formData);  /* Send to server */ 
   }

   /* Check the response status */  
   client.onreadystatechange = function() 
   {
      if (client.readyState == 4 && client.status == 200) 
      {
         alert(client.statusText);
      }
   }
</script>
```